# can mysql_query() return true?

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to check if a record with given id is present in the table or not. if it is true i have to execute certain statements if not i have to display an error.
so i thought of using mysql_query() statement like this:

```
mysql_query("select 'true' from people_info where id=1");
```

id=1 is present in the table.

instead of giving me "true" the above statement outputs Resource id#10.

when i give id=100 which is not in table

```
mysql_query("select 'true' from people_info where id=100");
```

it gives me Resource id#12

Comment: mysql_query returns a resource ID (as per the docs!). You then need to call mysql_fetch_row/mysql_fetch_array to retrieve the row data.

Answer (score 0):

We are missing some line of your code about how you output the value but this should work :

```
$result = mysql_query("select 'true' from people_info where id=1"); //This return a string
$value = mysql_result($result,0);
echo("My value is : " . $value);
```

Use `mysql_result`.
Here is the [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php). This function return the contents of one cell from a MySQL result set in a `String` format. Of course, for comparison you can cast or simply compare the value of the cell as a string to another string. Beware that this function can return false if nothing is returned.

Comment: i need to check it an if condition. if the `if(true)` condition is true i execute a certain set of statements

Comment: This method return a string, just compare it : if('true' == $value). Anyways, it's ain't the main question isn't?

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
list($value) = @mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select 'true' from people_info where id=100"));
```

Only INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success.